# Vim errorformat non-greedy match of %m operator

Tags: vim, vi

I have an errorfile which I want to be read by vi. The format looks as if:

```
myfile.txt_:_80_:_3_:_this is the message: oh no!_:_comment
```

I.e., filename, lineno, colno, message and comment separated by "_:_". Note the trailing "comment" which I do *not* want to appear in the vi message. However, when I use the errorformat string

```
:set errorformat=%f_:_%l_:_%c_:_%m
```

The "%m" operator has greedy matching and matches everything, including the whole "_:_comment" portion. This is even true if I make the errorformat

```
:set errorformat=%f_:_%l_:_%c_:_%m_:_
```

I do not know how to customize what text "%m" matches. The vi documentation speaks that pretty much everything that is possible with vi regex should be possible, but I cannot figure out a way to make it work (the documentation is vague in this respect in my opinion).

How can I use an errorformat that ignores the last column field?

Comment: As far as I understood this is a regex problem and not really a vim problem? I'm not particularly skilled with regex but you could try regex101.com or regexr.com

Comment: No, it isn't. I could perfectly format a regex to do this, it's trivial. I just don't know how to make vim interpret it as an errorformat %m portion.

Answer (score 1):

You can finish the format with the generic `%s` (for "search text"):

```
:set errorformat=%f_:_%l_:_%c_:_%m_:_%s
```

[image: example]

Note that this is relatively fragile. The following error, with several more `_:_` separators:

```
myfile.txt_:_80_:_3_:_this is the message: oh no!_:_comment_:_foo_:_bar
```

would give you this message:

```
this is the message: oh no!_:_comment_:_foo
```

Improvement opportunities:

- *outside of Vim*, make sure your errorfile is formatted in a non-ambiguous way,
- *in Vim*, use a function to transform ambiguous error strings into non-ambiguous ones, see `:help :cgetexpr`.

Comment: While appending '%s' works to remove the trailing garbage data, it unfortunately breaks functionality of jumping using :cn and :cp :-( It just doesn't jump anywhere anymore. When I remove '%s' I see the trailing garbage, but jumping works again. Very strange.

Comment: You are right, `%s` ends up becoming the search pattern used by Vim for jumping to errors, which is not good at all.